# Discrepancy passing data between view controllers

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to pass data between my first ViewController and my SecondViewController. I have two variables at the top of ViewController that are initialized as empty. I then get parse JSON data and set the value of these two variables to the parsed temporary JSON variables. I then in the prepareforSegue function, have the SecondViewController's variables equal to the first two variables in my first ViewController. For some reason the passed variables only pass the variables when they were empty. I'm not sure if I'm making any sense, but here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var stockSymbol = String()
var stockPrice = String()

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/\(textField.text!)/quote?format=json")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")

            do {

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                if let resources = json["list"]?!["resources"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                    if let fields = resources[0]["resource"]?["fields"] as? [String:String], price = fields["price"], symbol = fields["symbol"] {

                        self.stockSymbol = symbol
                        self.stockPrice = price

                        print(self.stockSymbol, self.stockPrice)
                    } 
                }

            } catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")

                //end catch
            }

        } //end if status code == 200
    } //end task


    task.resume()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //var test:String

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "searchResults") {

        print("working \(self.stockPrice)")
        let secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController;
        secondVC.passedSymbol = self.stockSymbol
        secondVC.passedPrice = self.stockPrice
        print(secondVC.passedSymbol)



    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Basically I want the stock price and symbol to be transferred to my second view controller's variables but it doesn't seem to work.

Code for Second View Controller:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var passedSymbol: String!
var passedPrice: String!

@IBOutlet weak var symbol: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("passed \(passedSymbol)")
    print("second view")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.symbol.text = self.passedSymbol
    self.price.text = self.passedPrice

    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Output statements when I put "aapl" into the searchField

```
working 

passed 
second view
Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.
AAPL 100.529999
```

Comment: Please show code for `SecondViewController` as well as the outputs of any print statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't do this:

```
var stockSymbol = String()
var stockPrice = String()
```

This is a bad habit that stops the compiler complaining about uninitialised variables but completely ignores the power of optionals in Swift.

Rather, do this:

```
var stockSymbol:String!
var stockPrice:String!
```

This will ensure that you get an exception when you try and use the variables without setting the values.

Now, the reason that you are getting empty values (or would get an exception if you made my suggested changes) is that you are initiating an asynchronous data fetch when the button is pressed but initiating the segue immediately, presumably because you have an action associated with the button as well as the `touchUpInside` handler.

You need to remove the action segue and create a programmatic segue by ctrl-dragging from the yellow `View Controller` icon at the top of your scene to the destination view controller and give the new segue an identifier as usual.

Then, you can change your `buttonPressed` function to invoke the segue once the data has been retrieved;

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/\(textField.text!)/quote?format=json")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")

            do {

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                if let resources = json["list"]?!["resources"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                    if let fields = resources[0]["resource"]?["fields"] as? [String:String], price = fields["price"], symbol = fields["symbol"] {

                        self.stockSymbol = symbol
                        self.stockPrice = price

                        print(self.stockSymbol, self.stockPrice)
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("searchResults",sender:sender)
                        })
                    } 
                }

            } catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")

                //end catch
            }

        } //end if status code == 200
    } //end task


    task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

the reason should be that when you go to the second viewcontroller, you have not got the data in the first viewcontroller. The dataTaskWithRequest is an async function, which means it runs on the other thread instead of the main ui thread. What you can do is wait until you get the data at the first viewcontroller and then call the segue. The print information on the console may puzzle you as if you have already got the data but actually it may occur after calling the segue and that results in no data passed.

Comment: what do you mean Remove the async? It itself is async.